# Mailto form for idea

Tags: html, forms, mailto

I am wanting to use a mailto form like the one below
`<form action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post"     enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br>   <br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>`

but instead of it sending it to a predefined address i want the user to be able to choose the address. I also want the user to choose a subject using a simple text box for both. Any help is highly appreciated thanks

Comment: You cannot do this directly with HTML. Are you able to use PHP (preferred) or Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use JavaScript to change the `action` attribute based on form inputs. If you put `id='my_form'` into `<form>` and have these fields:

Then a JavaScript function triggered by a button would do this

```
document.getElementById('my_form').setAttribute('action',
    'mailto:' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('email_to').value) +
    '?subject=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('subject').value)
);
```

Comment: The submit button needs to trigger the function which runs that code, and then submits the form, might be best to use `<button>` instead of `<input type='submit'...`. The `<form>` tag should have that `id='my_form'` attribute so that it can be found and have its attribute changed.